# How to fix datatables search box and pagination to right?

Tags: javascript, html, datatables

Search and pagination controls in datatable are showing in center by default.. I want to be them in right position as same as shown in datatables documentation

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#example').DataTable();
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<div class="box-body">
  <table id="example" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Partner Category/Partner Group</th>
        <th>Created At</th>
        <th>Action</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

[image: datatable]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a property called `dom` in datatable constructor which can be used to specify different options for datatables like pagination, search input etc.
The built-in options available are:

```
l - Length changing
f - Filtering input
t - The Table!
i - Information
p - Pagination
r - pRocessing
< and > - div elements
<"#id" and > - div with an id
<"class" and > - div with a class
<"#id.class" and > - div with an id and class
```

To manipulate the search input you can wrap that with class or ID and with the help of CSS you can achieve the positioning you want. Like this,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        "dom": '<"search"f>i'
    } );
} );
```